# How to put desktop icons in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: nautilus

I'd want to put Firefox, Rythmbox and Libreoffice in the desktop, but Ubuntu doesn't allow me to paste them directly, what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Nautilus, navigate to `/usr/share/applications`. Then copy and paste the .desktop-Files to your desktop.

You can also drag'n'drop from there with the middle mouse button (usually by clicking your scroll wheel) and choosing "Copy here" on the desktop.

Comment: Thank you,I tried,but it says I'm not allowed,even opening Nautilus as sudo.

Comment: Try it via the terminal (from your home directory): `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ./Desktop/firefox.desktop` and post the result

Comment: @Takkat. When you try to move it, yes, but when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> it should work.

Comment: @the_Seppi: drag & drop copy is broken in my 13.10 therefore I did not further elaborate it. You can <Alt>-drag and drop to select copy from the menu however.

Comment: Same problem in 14.04 LTS too, things are getting worse, what Ubuntu developers are doing, bugs are appearing again and again. First time Ubuntu users will cry just because of such silly things.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, navigate to `/usr/share/applications`, but rather than copy/paste (this will copy all of the files contents), right click and make a link then copy THAT which will just copy the icon and not the entire folder contents.