# Cannot add app shortcuts to desktop

Tags: 13.10

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, and ever since, I cannot add any application shortcut onto the desktop.

[image]

My desktop is blank right now, and it really sucks to have to open Unity or launch the terminal whenever I want to access an application. How do I get around this problem, its really frustrating.

Comment: From the looks of it, you are copying to the root folder. Can you confirm that you are copying to your desktop and not a root folder?

Comment: Im not. Im simply dragging an icon from Unity to the desktop, which, under normal circumstances should create a shortcut to the respective application.

Comment: Numix theme. Nice. Using it too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no icons on your desktop, then it is likely that your desktop is not being drawn by the file manager.

To fix this, install `gnome-tweak-tool`, and from there, enable the option to allow the file manager to draw the desktop:

[image: gtt]

Answer (score 1):

A solution is given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362608/how-to-put-desktop-icons-in-ubuntu-13-10).

In short, navigate to `/usr/share/applications` and copy-paste the .desktop files to your desktop.